# How to conditionally highlight nodes with matching values in Vega

Tags: vega-lite, vega, deneb

I'm trying to convert an existing behaviour in a custom Deneb visual, in Vega (full). Currently the code highlights all current node and it's ancestors in a tree

```
    {
      "name": "nodeHighlight",
      "value": "[0]",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {
            "type": "mouseover",
            "markname": "node"
          },
          "update": "pluck(treeAncestors('treeCalcs', datum['id']), 'id')"
        },
        {
          "events": {
            "type": "mouseout"
          },
          "update": "[0]"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I need it to highlight

- all nodes
- across the entire tree
- where the 'title' field matches the node in the mouseover.

I've been trying to change the update line to add a condition, but I cannot get this working.

Changing the treeAncestors function to data, returns all the node ids and highlights everything on the mouseover.

`"update": "pluck(data('treeCalcs', datum['id']), 'id')"`

But I cannot figure out how to add a filter to this to check for title field matching the mouseover value - any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That code looks familiar ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm feeling like a dumb-ass now!

I still don't have the solution for doing this by item code, but I changed the signal to a literal and the update to load the value for the datum['Title'] on mouseover.

Then it was a simple case of updating the highlighted mark code to check the Title value against he signal, rather then scan an array. Easy!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).